# Is necessary to add "trying" in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Person A: "Searching for Mr. Rainbow again?"
>
> Person B nodded, **still** **trying** **to hunt down** his imaginary friend.

Do I need the **trying**? Or I should just write: **still hunting down**?

Comment: It depends on what you mean. Is he trying to do something, or is he doing it? But the the phrase is an odd one in context either way. For one thing, it's redundant. His nod already indicates he is still "searching for Mr. Rainbow," so what needs to be said beyond that? More words may help fill out the page, but they don't necessarily improve communication.

Comment: Also, you'd be better off asking this on Writers.SE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, saying that someone is "trying" to do something indicates that he is not succeeding, or that his success is in doubt, while simply saying that he is doing it implies that he is doing it successfully. "I am making a lot of money" means that I actually am collecting the cash. "I am trying to make a lot of money" means that I have some scheme but it hasn't actually produced any cash yet, or that I just hope or wish to make a lot of money.

But in this case, the word "hunting" describes an activity that may or may not be successful. If I am hunting for something, I am attempting to find it, but I haven't actually found it yet. So there's not much difference between "hunting" and "trying to hunt". Unless, I suppose, you mean that I want to hunt for something, but I haven't been able to start yet for whatever reason.